# Css cut right side of an image

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a width of `~ 200px` and a height of `145px`, inside that div I place an Image which has a height of `145px` but a width of `210px`, how can I cut `10px` from the right side of the Image so that the Image fits into the Content of the div?

Comment: Can you share your code with us?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `overflow:hidden` for the div.The part of image portion ouside the div will be not be visible

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:145px;overflow:hidden;border: 1px solid green;">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/210x145" style="width:210px; height:145px;border: 1px solid red;">
</div>
```

Comment: @Micheasl if you want to fit the image inside the div use width:100%;

Answer (score 0):

> For Fit Image:

```
img {
   width:100%;
   //dont need height
}
```

> For Cut Image

```
div {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this is what you want @Micheasl. Otherwise please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 145px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzU5ODI0NDE4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMTE2MTI2._V1_SY154_SX210_AL_.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .cut-text {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        width:25px;
        height: 1.2em;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

```html
<h2>text-overflow: ellipsis:</h2>
<div class="cut-text">Hello world!</div>
```